# Modify the default recipe repository

Tags: repository, recipe, cloudify

I have modified the default recipe repository to point to my own github repository URL.

After the "bootstrap", I can see my recipes in the "work\cloudify_recipes_clone" but I don't see the recipe in the webui.

Answer (score 1):

The UI expects to find a structure similar to [cloudify-recipes repository](https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes)

Which means all you need is to create a folder "apps" and/or "services" and the UI will display the content under those folders.